# \MakeUppercase problems with babel

Tags: fonts, pdftex, header-footer, babel, bugs

Why doesn't this code work?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Flipa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! It works for me. However, loading `babel` should be loaded with some language option.

Comment: Please, explain what “doesn't work” means exactly.

Comment: assuming miktex: Update.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs detail/works for recent distribution (respectively after updating, if that was the issue).